# php: how to get indexed array of key values

Tags: php, arrays

Assuming I have an array like

```
$arr = array (
    array( 'foo' => 'Lorem' ),
    array( 'foo' => 'ipsum' ),
    array( 'foo' => 'dolor' ),
    array( 'foo' => 'sit'   )
);
```

How can I quickly convert this array into an indexed array for the key "foo"? So that the result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'Lorem'
    [1] => 'ipsum'
    [2] => 'dolor'
    [3] => 'sit'
)
```

Are there any quick ways with PHP functions? Or do I simply have to create a new array, iterate over the other one and insert the values manually.

Comment: @RahilWazir: it's not a duplicate. The solution to that other question is using `array_values`, however `array_values` will simply result in the same array in my case.

See Answers below.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) which is available from PHP 5.5

```
print_r(array_column($arr,'foo'));
```

### The code...

```
<?php
$arr = array (
    array( 'foo' => 'Lorem' ),
    array( 'foo' => 'ipsum' ),
    array( 'foo' => 'dolor' ),
    array( 'foo' => 'sit'   )
);

print_r(array_column($arr,'foo'));
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/99812)

Comment: Oh I see, too bad this wasn't introduced earlier :). So I guess I have to do it manually when PHP 5.5 is not available.

Comment: @Spooky: Or, you could say `if (!function_exists('array_column')) { function array_column($arr, $colname, $keyname=null) { /* do exactly what array_column does */ } }`, and once you switch to 5.5, you'll start using the built-in version automatically... :)

Comment: @cHao, That was perfect!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_map()`. This works -

```
$new_arr = array_map(function($v){return $v['foo'];}, $arr);
var_dump($new_arr);
//  OUTPUT
array
  0 => string 'Lorem' (length=5)
  1 => string 'ipsum' (length=5)
  2 => string 'dolor' (length=5)
  3 => string 'sit' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

.. Or using `array_map(..)`:

```
<?php
$arr = array (
    array( 'foo' => 'Lorem' ),
    array( 'foo' => 'ipsum' ),
    array( 'foo' => 'dolor' ),
    array( 'foo' => 'sit'   )
);

print_r(array_map(function($x){return $x["foo"];}, $arr));
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Lorem
    [1] => ipsum
    [2] => dolor
    [3] => sit
)
```