# PHP - How to get array value using its key?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

How do I get the value of an associative array using its key. For example, I have:

```
$new = array(

array(
"post" => "anything",
"newt" => "Nothing"
),
array(
"post" => "something",
"newt" => "Filthy"
),
    array(
"post" => "one value",
"newt" => "normal"
),
    array(
"post" => "two value",
"newt" => "happy"
),
    array(
"post" => "Three",
"newt" => "more"
)
);
```

Now I want to get the value of `post`. That means I want to get echoed `anything, something`. How do I accomplish this? I tried a way but that's not working. Example;

`print_r($new['post']);`

I also tried `echo $new['post'];` but doesn't work. Please help

Comment: `echo $new[0]['post'];` (returns:anything)  and `echo $new[1]['post'];` (returns:something)

Comment: What if I want both the values?

Comment: that is both the values (anything, something)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no prior research nor minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Comment: @Dagon I mean by one line of code either `print` or `echo` instead of two echoes

Comment: possible duplicate of [php: how to get indexed array of key values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657456/php-how-to-get-indexed-array-of-key-values)

Comment: `echo $new[0]['post'].' '.$new[1]['post'];` sorry this is really  *basic syntax* stuff you should learn

Comment: @Dagon Sorry I have edited my question. Is there a way to get all values at once rather than doing `echo $new[0]['post']` and 1,2,3 and so on. I mean something like `print_r($new['post'])` and it would print `value1,value2,value3,value4`

Comment: @user3293145 see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after the edit i guess you want more than 2 ?

so ..

```
foreach ($new as $n){
echo $n['post'].',';
}
```

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted. Thank you so much  :)

Comment: every one edits my answers ;( (usually trivially)

Answer (score 1):

**You can do like this**

```
foreach($new as $key => $value){
  echo $value['post']."<br/>"; 
}
```

**Incase you don't need the key:**

```
foreach($new as $value){
  echo $value['post']."<br/>"; 
}
```

## [Live Demo...](http://codepad.org/yuOLLLTY)

Answer (score 1):

**PHP >= 5.5.0**

```
foreach(array_column($new, 'post') as $post) {
  echo $post;
}
```